# Main Button to Filter Everything

Tags: excel-2010, business-intelligence, powerpivot

Goal:
Make a clear filter of everything and return to the standard list in the pivot table by pressing a main button. The button clear everything of what you have made some selection among slicer in PowerPivot in Excel 2010.

Problem:
There is no main button to do it. How should I get it?

Info:
The excel document has a pivot table that is connected to a powerpivot. In addtion I have three slicer with different selection. Each slicer has a small filter functionality. In my case, I want a main button to press it instead of pressing totally three times from slicers.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can clear all slicers at one time from the Excel menu:

1. Click on your pivot table.
2. On the PivotTable Tools menu, choose the Options tab.
3. Click the Clear button in the Actions Group and choose Filters
  [image: PivotTable Tools Options Tab]

If this is too many clicks, you can create a button that runs some VBA to clear all slicers at once.

1. On the Developer tab, click Insert and choose Button (Form Control).
2. Draw the button on the worksheet.
3. When the Assign Macro dialog box appears, choose New.
4. Paste this code in the Sub

   ```
   Dim cache As SlicerCache  
   For Each cache In ActiveWorkbook.SlicerCaches    
   cache.ClearManualFilter  
   Next cache
   ```
5. Save and close the VBA window.

Now when you click your button, all slicers should have their selections cleared. 
Source for VBA code: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff195843%28v=office.14%29.aspx